# Valgrind errors for using free() in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, valgrind, free

I am making a project using a hash array. I am putting an image i found online to show you guys what i'm trying to do. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsWlY.png)

So I've initialized the big array on the left like this in main:

```
cellule_t * array[HASH_MAX] = {NULL};
```

Then i have made all the insertions to create the linked lists. What i want to do now, is to free() all the memory allocated to create all this. So, like I'm not using malloc for the big array, i just need to free the linked lists and I'm using this function :

But i get some errors from Valgrind and the blocks are not freed.
I'm putting all the functions I use including the main to make it more clear.

```
typedef struct cell{

   char *mot;
   char *traduction;
   struct cell *suivant;

}cellule_t;

int main()
{
int indice;
cellule_t *cel;
FILE*file = NULL;
char buffer[100] = "hello bye glass sorry";    
cellule_t *tabMajeur[HASH_MAX] = {0};
file = fopen("fichier.txt","r");
remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,file);    (c:157)
affichageTraduction(tabMajeur,buffer);
libererMemorie(tabMajeur);  (c:159)

}

void remplissage_hachage (cellule_t **tabMajeur,FILE *fichier)
{
char  string1[20];
unsigned int indice = 0;
cellule_t *copy;
int boolean = 0;
char *string2, *string3 = NULL;
cellule_t *c =NULL;


while(fgets(string1,100,fichier) != NULL)
{
    string2 = strtok(string1,";");
    string3 = strtok(NULL,";"); 
    string3[strlen(string3)-1] = '\0';
    printf("string2 %s\n",string2);
    printf("string3 %s\n",string3);
    indice = hash_string(string2);
    boolean = 0;
    indice = recherche(tabMajeur,string2,&boolean,&c);

    if(boolean != 1) 
    {
        copy = tabMajeur[indice];
        tabMajeur[indice] = creationCellule(string2,string3); (c: 64)
        tabMajeur[indice]->suivant = copy;    
    }
}


}



cellule_t* creationCellule(char * mot, char *traduction)
{

  cellule_t *nouveau = (cellule_t *) malloc(sizeof(cellule_t)); (c:24)

  if(nouveau != NULL)
  {
    nouveau -> mot = strdup(mot);
    nouveau -> traduction = strdup(traduction);
    nouveau -> suivant = NULL;
  }

  return nouveau;

}



void libererMemorie(cellule_t **tabMajeur)
{

int i = 0;
cellule_t * cour;
cellule_t * copy;
for(i = 0 ; i < HASH_MAX; i++)
{
    cour = tabMajeur[i];
    while(cour != NULL)
    {
        copy = cour;
        free(copy); (c:137)
        cour = cour->suivant; (c:138)
    }

}
}
```

The valgrind error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GatPz.png)

The text for valgrind error is:

```
==2550== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2550== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2550== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2550== Command: ./tp4
==2550== 
string2 hello
string3 bonjour
string2 bye
string3 au revoir
string2 sorry
string3 pardon
string2 glass
string3 verre
La traduction est bonjour au revoir verre pardon 
==2550== Invalid read of size 8
==2550==    at 0x108E55: libererMemorie (tp4.c:138)
==2550==    by 0x108F85: main (tp4.c:159)
==2550==  Address 0x522ea40 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2550==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in 
   /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ==2550==    by 0x108E50: libererMemorie (tp4.c:137)
==2550==    by 0x108F85: main (tp4.c:159)
 ==2550==  Block was alloc'd at
==2550==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in 
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ==2550==    by 0x108A5D: creationCellule (tp4.c:24) 
 ==2550==    by 0x108BD8: remplissage_hachage (tp4.c:64)
==2550==    by 0x108F60: main (tp4.c:157)
==2550== 
==2550== 
==2550== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2550==     in use at exit: 605 bytes in 9 blocks
==2550==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 6 frees, 5,821 bytes allocated
==2550== 
==2550== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2550==    definitely lost: 53 bytes in 8 blocks
==2550==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2550==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2550==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==2550==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2550== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2550== 
==2550== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2550== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Can you please help me find out what's wrong?

Comment: I decided to put the whole code to make it more clear, but if it's not the case, the function which i use to free() the linked lists is libererMemoire.

Comment: @WillWost Can you please include the errors thrown by Valgrind?

Comment: You mean take a picture of all the errors ?

Comment: I tried it, but your code doesn't compile: `prog.c:13:1: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’`, `prog.c:13:13: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared`, `prog.c:15:22: error: ‘HASH_MAX’ undeclared`, ...

Comment: You can see it on the second picture I have put

Comment: Yeah, it can't compile because i haven't given you the file which has to be read

Comment: No, that would only be a runtime problem. It doesn't compile because that's not the whole code.

Comment: @WillWost No, I mean post *text*. Copy and paste all the Valgrind errors from the terminal and put them in your question.

Comment: Ok i will put it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Invalid Read" error may stem from the fact that while you have a singly-linked list for each bucket in your hash table, you are attempting to free the list node and then access the pointer to the next node after you've free'd the current node.

So basically here:

```
copy = cour;
free(copy);
cour = cour->suivant;
```

You are creating undefined behavior because you are freeing the node, then attempting to access the free'd memory via the `cour` pointer to get at the next pointer in the linked list.  Assigning `copy` the value of `cour` only copied the pointer value itself.  You then free'd the memory pointed to by both `copy` and `cour`, and then attempted to access the memory in a free'd block. Valgrind definitely won't like that.

You can simply change your ordering to the following:

```
copy = cour;
cour = cour->suivant;
free(copy);
```

Now you free the memory in the current node *after* copying out the pointer to the next node while the memory block is still a valid allocated memory block.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helped me ! I don't have errors anymoue, but the problem is that not all the blocks are freed and i don't understand why.

Comment: It's fine. I found out the problem. It's strdup which leaks the memory. Thank you !